# What is the proper installation order for VS2010 components? (IIS Express, SQL CE, MVC3, SP1 Beta)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2008-sp1, iis-express

After I went to http://www.microsoft.com/web to get the IIS Express and SQL CE my machine has been acting strange.  VS2010 intellisense is lost, and now I've lost my HTML designer.  It doesn't load.

Maybe it's because the Microsoft Web Platform the free [developer express](http://www.microsoft.com/web) alongside VS2010 Ultimate.  Maybe the issues are relating to any of the other components I have installed: SP1, MVC 3, or maybe even the Azure SDK.  Now that I'm starting from a clean Virtual PC, I want to do it correctly.  Can someone look at my components below and let me know what problems or conflicts I'll run into?

My current base install is a clean VS2010 Ultimate install with Windows 7.  What is the proper installation order for the following components:

- Blend
- IIS Express
- SQL CE
- MVC 3
- Azure Service Bus
- Azure App Fabric (production, not labs)
- VS2010 SP1 Beta
- Office Tools

Also I think it's a good idea to install the SQL 2010 Administrative Tools as well, since I can manage my SQL Express instances with that as well.  What is your opinion?

Am I required to install Visual Studio Web Developer Express (free edition?)

Comment: This is on topic and relating to the reliable setup of a developer's workstation. I don't understand who would be better to ask than developers involved in these technologies. Sysadmins do no have a clue as far as this goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by installing VS2010 (the [edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products) you would choose would obviously depend on your budget). As far as the other components are concerned the order in which they are being installed is not really important.

Comment: Does the Microsoft Web Platform install things that may cause problems?  It installs Web Express.  Does that mean I apply SP1 before or after  (for example)

Comment: You install the SP1 after VS2010. Also note that the VS2010 SP1 is in  Beta.

Comment: The one item I'd toss out is make sure that if you need IIS, it has been installed before you install Visual Studio. This just helps ensure that IIS gets wired up properly for .net. If you don't, you can still fix it, just requires some manual steps.